Garage Door Opener Button Not Working on First Press
I have a Chamberlain garage door opener. It's one of the myQ based ones that is about 1 year old. Anyway when I go to open or close the door usually the button will not work on the first press. On the second press it will work correctly. There is no clicking, or movement of the door like it is trying to do anything.
When I first got the opener, it did work correctly.
I have removed and re-adopted the switch to the opener, and temporarily removed the LED (non garage door opener bulbs) but it still does it almost every time.
The weird part is that if we use our remotes (my car, the exterior keypad, or the provided remotes) it works every single time for opening and closing.
Anyone ever have this happen before and what was the resolution? I was thinking about getting the wall switch replaced (whether it's under warranty or I have to buy one).

Please specify where this button is located.

It is mounted to the wall about 12 - 15 ft away from the opener.

Not knowing how this switch is built (membrane or physical, direct wire or wireless ) this sounds like dirty or worn contacts.

what happens if you press and hold the button?  ... what happens if you press and wiggle the button?

maybe the double press is some kind of a lock override
